# What Is the Best UBUNTU script for installing LAMP

Tags: mysql, lamp

I  have tried to install LAMP on Ubuntu 14.04LTS
Cant get PHPmyAdmin to work and access MYSQL
Where is the clearest set of instructions to install LAMP

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

You can install the LAMP stak and phpmyadmin in a single command using the `apt-get` [tasksel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel#Usage_.28alternative.29) mode (don't forget the final `^`):

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to install `tasksel` at first by `sudo apt-get install tasksel`.
Then there are two processes to install LAMP server--
1.Give the command `sudo tasksel`. You will get the following window-
[image: List of servers]

Here press the down-arrow to select the server you want to install(In your case it is LAMP). Press tab to select,then `ok`. Now go on and install it!.

2.You can directly install it without seeing the list of servers by giving `sudo tasksel install lamp-server` and the installation process will start.

Now install phpmyadmin by `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`

Comment: "You have to install tasksel at first by sudo apt-get install tasksel" not true: `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` will install a lampserver user the tasksel task (see the list of tasks for apt-get related to ^)

Comment: That's not fundamental I think because the server to be installed in debian system are maintained by tasksel.So the user has to know what is 'tasksel'. Isn't it?

Comment: No not really. All they need to know is that "^" will install a pre-defined tasks; there is no longer a need to install or know about tasksel itself/ (I wonder why that ^ method seems so unknown to lots of people :P )

Comment: Yes you are right.But I was wondering in future,many other servers (or other stuffs) can be installed through tasksel,so I mentioned it for convenience ;)

Comment: Ah ok! But -all- of these can be used with apt-get and a ^ (the list with tasks is very long ;) )

Comment: Yes ^ is a handy one,but some people doesn't know whether it is 'lamp-server' or 'LAMP-server' ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should take care of installing Lamp Server.

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ phpmyadmin
```

`lamp-server^` runs apt-get in tasksel mode.

It doesn't look like tasksel lamp-server task installs phpmyadmin

```
sudo tasksel  --task-packages lamp-server
libmysqlclient18
libwrap0
apache2
libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
tcpd
apache2.2-common 
apache2-utils
libswitch-perl
libaprutil1
libaprutil1-ldap
libclass-isa-perl
libdbi-perl
libplrpc-perl
mysql-server
apache2.2-bin
mysql-client-5.5
mysql-server-5.5
libdbd-mysql-perl
libcap2
libhtml-template-perl
perl-modules
libnet-daemon-perl
libapr1
perl
mysql-server-core-5.5
mysql-client-core-5.5
ssl-cert
apache2-mpm-prefork
```

Therefore we need to add phpmyadmin too.

Comment: I can do this 1 line shorter. See my edit.