# LAMP-similar package bundle for Python stack

Tags: apt, python, lamp

In Ubuntu, we can install [LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)) stack in [one command](https://askubuntu.com/a/520067/22308) easily and start working on [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP).

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel -y
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

I wonder if there is similar bundle for [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)) stack? My [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=LAMP-similar%20package%20bundle%20for%20Python%20stack&oq=LAMP-similar%20package%20bundle%20for%20Python%20stack&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.177j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) shows little helpful result e.g. [this quora one](https://www.quora.com/What-is-Python-full-stack-called-like-LAMP-and-how-good-it-is-relatively-with-LAMP).

Comment: I'd say Python stack isn't popular enough for anyone to create a task for it.

Comment: Agree for the past time; though it become one soon in my view.